# MySQL counting points

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this (simplified) runs table where each finished run counts as a point:

```
| email | finished |
|-------|----------|
|    a  |     1    |
|    a  |     1    |
|    a  |     0    |
|    b  |     1    |
|    c  |     0    |
```

I have this

```
SELECT *, COUNT( * ) AS points 
FROM  `runs` 
WHERE finished IS TRUE
GROUP BY email
```

Result is:

```
| email |  points  |
|-------|----------|
|    a  |     2    |
|    b  |     1    |
```

The problem is that I also want the information about C, which has 0 points as C hasn't finished a run yet

Expected result:

```
| email |  points  |
|-------|----------|
|    a  |     2    |
|    b  |     1    |
|    c  |     0    |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `where` clause :

```
SELECT r.email, SUM( finished IS TRUE ) AS points 
FROM  `runs` r 
GROUP BY email;
```

Yes you can remove filtration also in `sum()` :

```
SELECT r.email, SUM(finished) AS points 
FROM  `runs` r 
GROUP BY email;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum` instead:

```
SELECT email, sum(finished) AS points 
  FROM  `runs` 
  GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT email, sum(finished) AS points FROM  `runs` GROUP BY email;
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/

Comment: In which way is this answer different to Nir levy's  ?

Comment: Please link to the official documentation, w3schools (w3fools) has a bad name for good reasons on this website

Comment: @collapsar In Mysql the data type Boolean is an alias of `TINYINT(1)` so summing in booleans is valid.

Comment: @forpas Yes, just saw it when running a test. Thank you for saving me the time to consult the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your finished into `int` type and do the sum.

```
    SELECT *, sum( cast(finished as int) ) AS points 
    FROM  `runs` 
    GROUP BY email
```

Comment: the CAST is pretty much redundant here as MySQL is a loose typed RDMS  also the finished always seams to be a INT datatype,..